# How to solve $0=\cos{2x}+\cos x$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm desperately trying to solve
$$0=\cos{2x}+\cos x$$

Am I on the right track when I'm this far?
$$\cos x(2\cos x+1)=1$$

I don't know where to go from here. What method can I use to further solve the equation? And how do these methods work?

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track. I would expand $\cos 2x = 2\cos^2 x -1$, then put $c = \cos x$ and solve the resulting quadratic equation in $c$.

Comment: You were close but no apples yet!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

remember the identity $\cos (2x)=\cos^2 (x)-\sin^2(x)=2\cos ^2 (x)-1$.

You want to solve $2\cos ^2 (x)-1+\cos (x)=0$. Let $t= \cos (x)$.

The question $2t^2+t-1=0$ and is easier to solve. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Is there an easy way to find the quadratic equation or is it just practice by doing?

Comment: These questions (and generally trigonometry questions I find) rely heavily on how well you know trigonometric identities. As you can see, if you remember the identity for $\cos(2x)$ this question is easier. My advice would be to practice and memorize (or even better, prove!) trigonometric identities.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\cos{2x}=cos^2{x}-\sin^2{x}=\cos^2{x}-(1-\cos^2{x})=2\cos^2{x}-1$

Then

$$\cos{2x}+\cos{x}=2\cos^2{x}+\cos{x}-1=(\cos{x}+1)(2\cos{x}-1)=0$$

Thus we solve

$$\cos{x}=-1 \text{ and } \cos{x}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Can you get it from here?

Answer (score 3):

We have

$$0=\cos 2x+\cos x\iff0=2\cos^2x+\cos x-1$$
so let $t=\cos x$ then
$$0=2t^2+t-1$$
and the two roots are
$$-1\quad;\quad\frac12$$
so
$$\cos x=-1\iff x=\pi+2k\pi$$
and
$$\cos x=\frac12\iff x=\left(\frac\pi3+2k\pi\right)\lor\left(x=-\frac\pi3+2k\pi\right)$$

Comment: Very nice flow!

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't remember trig identities, there is a geometric way to solve this. Imagine an origin-centered unit circle. $\cos(\theta)$ is the horizontal component of a radius at angle $\theta$ from the $x$ axis. Now $\cos(\theta)=-\cos(2\theta)$ has a geometric interpretation: the horizontal component of a radius at angle at $\theta$ is the negation of the horizontal component of a radius at angle $2\theta$.

There are two solutions: one where $\theta$ is in the first quadrant (with positive cosine) and $2\theta$ is in the second quadrant (with negative cosine), making a symmetry about the positive $y$ axis, and a similar case with symmetry about the negative $y$ axis. You can see that the first case occurs when $\theta$ is $\frac{1}{3}$ of the way to the negative $x$ axis and the second case occurs when $\theta$ is along the negative $x$ axis.

Comment: Very nicely done! I like geometric solutions that require more intuition rather than memory or knowledge

Answer (score 2):

$$\cos2x=-\cos x=\cos(\pi-x)$$

$$\implies2x=2m\pi\pm(\pi-x)$$ where $m$ is any integer

Now consider the signs one by one.

Observe that the set of solutions by '-' sign is a proper subset of the set of solutions by '+' sign

Comment: @user1211030, Observe that this is susceptible to generalization $$\cos mx+\cos nx=0$$